# httpGet return 406 when I add something after slash in route

Tags: c#, swagger, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I don't know why I get 406 error when I write my route like that **"teste/teste"**:

```
[HttpGet("teste/teste", Name = nameof(GetAsync))]
        [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(CommonApiConventions),
                    nameof(CommonApiConventions.Get))]
        [Authorize(nameof(DefaultScopePolicy.read))]
```

while its work when I name my route only **"teste/"**:

```
[HttpGet("teste/", Name = nameof(GetAsync))]
        [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(CommonApiConventions),
                    nameof(CommonApiConventions.Get))]
        [Authorize(nameof(DefaultScopePolicy.read))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting your route value by repeating the same name? Is teste the name of your controller? You should set your base route at the top of your controller declaration like that:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ControllerName
{

}
```

and then your method within the class

```
[HttpGet]
public function Get()
{

}
```